# infopath 2010 with sharepoint 2010 javascript error

Tags: infopath, error, forms-services

I have an infopath form with a datepicker control published to SharePoint. When I open the form from the server it works correctly. When I open the form from the client machine it generates a javascript error on the left side of the form, and when I open the error I see the following:

> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;
>   Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR
>   3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3; Media Center PC 6.0)
>   Timestamp: Wed, 27 Jul 2011 06:57:59 UTC
>
> Message: Syntax error Line: 2 Char: 1 Code: 0 URI:
>   http://servername/_layouts/FormResource.aspx?culture=1033&version=1
>
> Message: 'dateTime1033' is undefined Line: 2 Char: 51921 Code: 0 URI:
>   http://servername/_layouts/inc/Core.js?rev=8PdoqL6fQahtzwwVSZ2lpw%3D%3D

Any ideas?

Comment: Some things to check...What zone (i.e. Trusted) is the site running in your browser? Have you tried opening it on another client machine, with and without a different browser version?